# TableView into View of a ViewController Swift functions are not called

Tags: ios, swift, function, uitableview

When I add A `TableViewController` everything works fine, because I override the functions.
I've made the official apple tutorial and its like my code below.

Did I missed something or is it a bug?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    var data = ["Ferrari","Porsche"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{

        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        return data.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you missed many things. It's not a bug. :)

Comment: Can you help me at this point? @DharmeshKheni

Comment: see http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Comment: thanks it works now XD

Comment: i finally understood delegates in swift :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing delegates and reference for `tableView`.

Connect tableView with your class and then add the following in the viewDidLoad:

```
self.yourTableView.delegate = self
self.yourTableView.dataSource = self
```

And that's it.

You can assign `delegate` and `dataSource` through IB as well: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/set_object_delegate.html

Comment: Thank you :) Omg its a little embarrasing XD

Answer (score 1):

Drag a `tableView` in your viewController in storyBoard:

[image]

After that connect it's `IBOutlet` this way:

[image]

After that add this code in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
//assign delegate and datasource
tableview.dataSource = self
tableview.delegate = self

//register your tableview cell
self.tableview.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Change your `ReusableCellIdentifier` with `"cell"` into `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and it will look like:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Final code will be:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    var data = ["Ferrari","Porsche"]

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableview.dataSource = self
        tableview.delegate = self

        self.tableview.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{

        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

For more Info refer [THIS](https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/) tutorial.